# Successful delivery notification in biztalk filter port

Tags: ftp, biztalk, biztalk-2010, send-port

I have a FTP send port on which I want a successful delivery notification on successful upload of the file. The FTP send port is directly bound to a direct send port in the orchestration, using a filter expression, as I have multiple send ports for that direct send port based on the content of the message.

Is there a way I can achieve a successful delivery notification when the files are successfully uploaded to the FTP location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Delivery Notifications on the Send Ports.  Here's a good blog on the topic: http://kentweare.blogspot.com/2007/11/biztalk-delivery-notification.html

Just keep in mind that this is not Guaranteed Delivery, especially with a protocol like FTP.  Basically, you will get the successful ACK if the Adapter sent the message without error.  This is not a problem with BizTalk, rather FTP is in no way transactional and anything that goes wrong on the server is out reach of your app.

Comment: hi boatseller, the problem here is I have a direct binding send port which publishes messages to the message box and then have some send ports with some content based routing from the direct send port.

Comment: You can try this workaround then: http://www.agilior.pt/blogs/bruno.camara/archive/2008/04/17/4344.aspx. Basically, you're manually invoking the Delivery Notification.

Comment: I tried this but am facing some issues with the subscription of ACK messages mentioned in the link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a69abd6a-eec3-4474-bb20-672b94a87e4b/routing-failure-when-resumn-instance. It seems to be a biztalk version issue, I am currently using BizTalk 2010